# Oracle Multiple update Query in a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

is it possible

Table AA

```
ID_USER      PERIOD          SALARY      overtime    overtime_wages  bonus
1001        1-MAY-2012         $50         13             $3.5         -

1002        1-MAY-2012         $60         16             $5           -
1001        1-JUN-2012         $50         10             $3.5         -

1002        1-JUN-2012         $60         7              $5           -
```

if i want to find the value of bonuses with the following provisions:

```
if overtime * overtime_wages <= $ 15 then $ 5 bonus
if overtime * overtime_wages between $ 15 and $ 20 the bonus $ 7
if overtime * overtime_wages >= $ 20 then $ 10 bonus
```

how to resolve the logic ?
Here's my script :

```
UPDATE "AA" A 
SET A.BONUS = ( select (( A.OVERTIME*A.OVERTIME_WAGES)<= $ 15)=$5 or
                       (( A.OVERTIME*A.OVERTIME_WAGES) between $ 15 and $ 20 )=$7 or
                       (( A.OVERTIME*A.OVERTIME_WAGES)>= $ 20)=$10 
FROM "AA" A )
```

Comment: <code>
UPDATE "AA" A 
SET A.BONUS = ( select (( A.OVERTIME*A.OVERTIME_WAGES)<= $ 15)=$5 or
                       (( A.OVERTIME*A.OVERTIME_WAGES) between $ 15 and $ 20 )=$7 or
                       (( A.OVERTIME*A.OVERTIME_WAGES)>= $ 20)=$10 
FROM "AA" A )
</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `case` statement:

```
UPDATE "AA" A 
    SET A.BONUS = (case when A.OVERTIME*A.OVERTIME_WAGES <= 15 then 5
                        when A.OVERTIME*A.OVERTIME_WAGES between 15 and 20 then 7
                        when A.OVERTIME*A.OVERTIME_WAGES >= 20 then 10 
                   end);
```

You can actually simplify this to:

```
UPDATE "AA" A 
    SET A.BONUS = (case when A.OVERTIME*A.OVERTIME_WAGES <= 15 then 5
                        when A.OVERTIME*A.OVERTIME_WAGES <= 20 then 7
                        else 10 
                   end);
```